# animate ScrollTop and window scrollTop not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm try to make two **scrollTop** function. But it's not working. It's conflicting or calculating wrong. My first function for **fixed header animation** and second function for specific section **animate scrollTop**.
First function:

```
// HEADER SCROLL FUNCTION
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.main-menu').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    } else {
        $('.main-menu').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
});
```

Second function:

```
/* scrollTop function */
$(function () {
   var headerHeight = $(".main-menu").height();

   $('a[href^="\\#"]').on('click',function (e) {

       e.preventDefault();

       var target = this.hash,
       $target = $(target);

       $('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - headerHeight}, 1200);
    });
});
```

Here is the live **example** for two function.

*without header* animation: http://rahulmoral.com/portfolio/goldsafe/

*with header* animation: http://rahulmoral.com/portfolio/goldsafe-hp/

Main issue is without header animation animate scrollTop function working well. But When I write header animation then it's not working. I don't understand why my code is not working.

Thanks.